# knowing hidden connections on windows

Tags: windows, connection

I want to ask you if there's a program for windows to knowing hidden connections on windows

**To clarify**

Mozilla firefox, IDMAN and other programmes check every time for updates, but the connection here is hidden

**Note**

I mean connection to the links for updates (E.G : http://site.com/updates_checker)

Thanks in  advance

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

netstat -ao

This will show you for each PID, all connections. Then you can filter by the process you want to inspect (maybe with a PS script where you pass the image name)

Otherwise you could do netstat -ab this will show you the process name, but requires privilege elevation, takes time and the ouput format is not very good.

Answer (score 0):

To quote a post from [What's the closest equivalent of Little Snitch (Mac program) on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/261440/whats-the-closest-equivalent-of-little-snitch-mac-program-on-windows)

```
I always preferred NetLimiter over any other solution I've tried.

NetLimiter used to be only about bandwidth control and it still shines at that. But a personal firewall feature was added later on.

What primarily distinguishes it from the Windows firewall is that it will not allow any connection attempt to succeed before you decided how you want to handle it.
```