# Windows Firewall closing all outbound

Tags: windows, firewall

I was thinking about using built in windows firewall to maximise the security in my local domain envirement.
I want to close ALL outbound & inbound connections and then starting building rules to allow what is needed. the very first problem i encounter is something simple like web surfing.
after closing all outbound connections i make rules for 80,443 and dns 53 to allow traffic.
computer still cant surf the net, im guessing im missing something?
also any help on how to start with this would be great as im guessing there's loooots of ports to configure

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/261440/whats-the-closest-equivalent-of-little-snitch-mac-program-on-windows

Comment: See answer here, be sure you check all "**profiles**" as listed in the screen shot there for **public, private, and domain** and see if that helps with the outbound traffic: https://superuser.com/questions/1309756/not-able-to-access-ftp-server-from-other-machines-in-same-lan-when-windows-firew/1309760#1309760. It is likely the network adapter is classified by Windows with a profile you do not have checked in those FW rules. I would also provide your question with some screen shots and such of how you have the FW rules configured that are not working as expected.

Comment: I actually did a rule for ALL profiles, allowing outbound for 80,443,8080 tcp. cannot surf the web, however if i create a rule for example to exclude chrome and allow it on outbound, i can surf with chrome

Comment: I'd have to see the rules but did you allow TCP and UDP both for the DNS port `53`? The allow rules should be processed before the deny everything rule or whatever you have setup to block everything.

Comment: I use this app, makes it so much easier to do what you want>>>>>https://www.binisoft.org/wfc.php